# how to declare this variable outside if else loop

Tags: php

so here is my problem; i am working on some code that has been handed to me by other team-members (not my code); so it is quite in depth & tedious to figure out where all the variables and such match up, i managed to find out this piece that was giving me trouble in why my code here did not work

```
<td nowrap style="border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;

                     <?=$display_balance_details;?>
```

this code apparently sets it so that $display_balance_details is only set on certain pages, my problem is that I am trying to move this to the header of all the webpages;

```
    else if ($section == 'history')
    {
        $user = new user();
        $user->setts = &$setts;

        $row_user = $db->get_sql_row("SELECT * FROM
            " . DB_PREFIX . "users WHERE user_id=" . $session->value('user_id'));

        $template->set('user_details', $row_user);

        $template->set('display_account_status', $user->account_status($row_user['active'], $row_user['approved']));

        $user_payment_mode = $fees->user_payment_mode($session->value('user_id'));
        $template->set('user_payment_mode', $user_payment_mode);

        $template->set('display_payment_mode', $user->payment_mode_desc($user_payment_mode));

        (string) $display_balance_details = null;
        $display_balance_details = $user->show_balance($row_user['balance'], $setts['currency']);

        if ($user_payment_mode == 2 && $row_user['balance']>=$setts['min_invoice_value'])
        {
            $display_balance_details .= ' [ <a href="fee_payment.php?do=clear_balance">' . MSG_CLEAR_ACC_BALANCE . '</a> ]';
        }

        $template->set('display_balance_details', $display_balance_details);

        $show_history_table = false;
```

and this code tells what pages to set it on

```
<? } else if ($page == 'account') { ?>
<td nowrap <?=(($section == 'history') ? 'class="subcell_a"' : 'class="subcell_u"');?>><a href="<?=process_link('members_area', array('page' => 'account', 'section' => 'history'));?>">
```

so my problem is how to set $display_balance_details without removing the $section == 'history' bit (because this might cause a bunch of other problems down the road, not sure how the code is written) and how to best approach this issue?

Comment: "might cause a bunch of other problems down the road, not sure how the code is written" I'd recommend digging deeper and finding out how the code really works.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variable global:

```
global $display_balance_details;
```

or you declare $display_balance_details before if:

```
(string) $display_balance_details = null;
if ($section == 'history')
{
your code
}
```